# Not able to update the shelter Registry after removing one JSON from one array field of an asset

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

```
{

 "$class": "org.disaster.model.Shelter",

 "Shelter_Id": "1",

 "resident":

  [
     {
       "$class": "org.disaster.model.ResidentUpdate",
       "Name": "Nisi consequat et.",
       "Contact": "Magna duis.",
       "Biometric": "NiOmW=",
       "BloodGroup": "Voluptate pariatur exercitation elit." 
     },
     {
       "$class": "org.disaster.model.ResidentUpdate",
       "Name": "Amet et exercitation adipisicing non.",
       "Contact": "Lorem dolor deserunt quis.",
       "Biometric": "BhyWI=",
       "BloodGroup": "Et non minim commodo consectetur."
     }
  ]

}
```

I want to remove

```
{

 "$class": "org.disaster.model.ResidentUpdate",

 "Name": "Nisi consequat et.",

 "Contact": "Magna duis.",

 "Biometric": "NiOmW=",

 "BloodGroup": "Voluptate pariatur exercitation elit."

}
```

This JSON by querying on biometric field.

In console its coming properly.

But I am getting Error:

> Expected a Resource or Concept when I am trying to update shelter
>   registry.

(may be because I am trying to update the result field which is a variable but I am not getting how to use concept or resource here.)

**Seems to work on all versions of playground. Tested on Windows with Chrome.

```
> ##Script.js##

    /**
 * updateShelterStatus
 * @param {org.disaster.model.changeshelterstatus} people
 * @transaction
 */
 async function ChangeShelterStatus(people) {

   var factory = getFactory();
   var shelterId

   const resident = await query('selectResidentByBiometric',{'biometric': people.Biometric});
   var email=resident[0].Resident_Email
   var residentRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.disaster.model.Resident');
   var residentObj = await residentRegistry.get(email);
   console.log(residentObj.shelter)
   if(residentObj.shelter.length>0){
      for(var k=0;k<residentObj.shelter.length;k++){
        console.log("OLD"+residentObj.shelter[k].Status)
        shelterId=residentObj.shelter[k].shelterId.getIdentifier()
        console.log("Shelter Id"+shelterId)
        residentObj.shelter[k].Status='Moved'
        console.log("New"+residentObj.shelter[k].Status)
        await residentRegistry.update(residentObj)
        console.log("Updated")

 }
   }
   else{
        alert("First Entry")

   }


   for(var j=0;j<residentObj.shelter.length;j++){
   var shelterRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.disaster.model.Shelter');

         var shelterObj=await shelterRegistry.get(shelterId);


        for(var i=0;i<shelterObj.resident.length;i++){
        if(shelterObj.resident[i].Resident_Email==email){
          console.log(shelterObj.resident,shelterObj.resident[i])
        remove_array_value(shelterObj.resident,shelterObj.resident[i]);
       }}}
 }


async function remove_array_value(array, value) {
  console.log("In Remove")
    var index = array.indexOf(value);
    if (index >= 0) {
        array.splice(index,1);
        reindex_array(array);
    }
}
async function reindex_array(array) {
    console.log("In ReIndex")
  var shelterRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.disaster.model.Shelter');
   var result = [];
    for (var key in array) {
      result.push(array[key]);

    }
    await shelterRegistry.update(result)
          console.log("After delete")
}

> ##Model File##



     transaction changeshelterstatus{
  o String Biometric
}
```

Comment: so you want to remove one element of the `resident[]` concept array? Can you post your transaction code + model ? Would make things easier to fix :-) – Paul O'Mahony 13 mins ago

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony I have added  transaction code and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code could be a lot simpler (not sure you need additional functions you wrote etc) - but here is an example below - you can translate to your environment (I don't have your model). The function below should take care of indexing the newly modified array.

ps. (yours is a concept array containing JSON elements, but I've posted a commented simple array example here as well FYI):

Given this simple model

```
 asset Tradeable identified by id {
   o String id
   o conArray[] myArray
 }

 concept conArray {
   o String mystring1
   o String mystring2
 }
```

and transaction modeled like this:

```
transaction arrTx {
  --> Tradeable tradeable
}
```

My logic to update an array (either multiple elements or single in a concept array) is below - I've tested this against the local Composer Dev Fabric environment (v1.1) and works fine.

```
/**
 * Sample transaction
 * @param {org.example.trading.arrTx} tx
 * @transaction
 */
async function myfunc(tx) {


    var asset = tx.tradeable;

    // removing JSON element from a JSON array by match eg. concept array eg element(s) with a particular field having a value match 'abc'

   for (var i =0; i < asset.myArray.length; i++) {

      if (asset.myArray[i].mystring1.indexOf('abc') > -1 ) {
         asset.myArray.splice(i,1);
         // break;  // if you only want remove 1st occurrence FYI uncomment this line, otherwise it removes all matching entries from the array
      }
   }

   tx.tradeable.myArray = asset.myArray;
   var assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.trading.Tradeable');
   await assetRegistry.update(tx.tradeable);

}
```

Finally - just posting for others to read if they need to - to remove an element from a simple array (replace the concept array code above)

// FYI - removing straightforward array element (non-concept)

```
 /*
    if (asset.myArray) { 
       var index = asset.myArray.indexOf('abc');
       if (index >= 0) {
           asset.myArray.splice(index,1);
       }
   }
   */
```

Comment: The issue is resolved. Thank you for the idea. I have created one asset and transaction , updated the asset  and pass it through the transaction and delete the field.